# to check whether the symbol ½ matches the value in table - MSAccess, PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I am having a table with value ½ in a column and I have to use a query to count the number of rows which has value ½.

( used the query like this

```
$sql="select count(*) as aaa from table1 where Code1='½'";
$s=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
odbc_fetch_row($s);
echo odbc_result($s,"aaa");
```

But it returns 0, but I have 4 rows with this value. Why it is not recognizing?

Comment: instead of 1/2 try it with .5

Comment: Does the string '½' comprise the whole value, or do you need the LIKE operator with wildcards?

Comment: let me know if that works.

Comment: @brandonWhe its not the value its a short text column, that ½ is a string there. ½ i mentioned here is not actually ½, it is like ½A or ½P or something..

Comment: @DonJewett that ½ is a string there. ½ i mentioned here is not actually ½, it is like ½A or ½P or something..

Comment: Then try WHERE Code1 LIKE '½%'

Comment: @DonJewett Tried that too, not working displays 0 only

Comment: This question is tagged as pertaining to `ms-access` but it looks like you might be working directly with MySQL from PHP. Is the `ms-access` tag really relevant?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm using MSAccess DB in PHP

Comment: Then why does your question specifically mention "a Mysql table"?

Comment: @GordThompson Sorry.. i wrongly mentioned it.. Edited the question.. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Now is the `mysql` tag relevant?

Comment: @GordThompson Removed Mysql tag.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access says `Asc("½")` is 189.  So use `Chr(189)` to refer to the character whose ASCII value is 189.

```sql
select count(*) as aaa from table1 where Code1=Chr(189)
```

If your match text includes another character following ½ ... for example ½P ...  concatenate it with `Chr(189)`:

```sql
select count(*) as aaa from table1 where Code1=Chr(189) & 'P'
```

Comment: Thank you.. Thank you.. Its working. perfect answer.. :-)